# Excel vba kill an invisible application after an error

Tags: vba, excel

I have an application that first creates an invisible application:

```
        Dim ExcelApp As Object
        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelApp.Visible = False
        ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        ExcelApp.EnableEvents = False
```

And then proceeds to use it to open files invisibly:

```
      Do While fileTitle <> ""
          Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
          Set dataWorkbook = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileTitle)
```

At the end of the operations with the file macros closes the file:

```
          dataWorkbook.Close
          fileTitle = Dir()
         Loop
```

At the end of the sub macros closes the application:

```
      ExcelApp.Quit
      Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, if an error occurs before the file is closed, the invisible file and the application would never be closed and would continue to linger in operation systems not only eating away the memory and resources, but also preventing from doing any operations with the opened filed - renaming, opening or editting it.

I wonder if there is a way to close both the file and the application if an error occurs - in the current macros or to create a separate macros that detects invisible applications no variable points to and closes it.

Comment: Use the [`On Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement)-Statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the top of your procedure use an error handler like

```
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error Goto CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR
  'With that line you tell VBA to jump to the closing part if an error happens
```

and use this goto marker before you close the file.

```
CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR:
    ExcelApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Note: You don't need to `Set ExcelApp = Nothing`  because Excel does this automatically on `End Sub`.

---

#### Edit due to comments

If you need to show error messages or something then your code has to be extended like this:

```
    ExcelApp.Quit 'This is needed to regularly quit if there is no error
    Exit Sub 'Don't run into error handling if there was no exeption

CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR:
    Application.StatusBar = "Error occured"
    ExcelApp.Quit 'This is needed to quit after an exeption if there is an error
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, do I understand correctly that `ExcelApp.Quit` quits all the workbooks opened inside a given application instance, so that I don't need to `dataWorkbook.Close` specifically?

Comment: @ans Yes `ExcelApp.Quit` quits exactly the instance you opened with `Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` nothing more! All workbooks inside that instance obviously get closed too then.

Comment: I encountered a bit of a problem now. I added `CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR: Application.StatusBar = "Error occured" ExcelApp.Quit` at the end of the sub and the `On Error GoTo CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR` at the beginning. The problem is, now even if the code runs without errors, when it reaches the `CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR` it executes the code and changes the status bar..

Comment: @Ans: Peh forgot to show you that you need an `Exit Sub` on the line before the label `CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR:`.  Using that command will keep the good code from running the error code at the end.  Just don't forget to 'quit' you app in the good code as well.

Comment: @abraxascarab Thank you, sir.

Comment: @abraxascarab No Peh did not forgot to show that. Everything changed because @ans inserted `Application.StatusBar = "Error occured"`. Because if you have an `Exit Sub` before `CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR:` then the `ExcelApp` will remain open forever if there is no error. If you do that then you will also need another `ExcelApp.Quit` before the `Exit Sub` to quit it if there is no error. (see my edit).

Comment: @Peh I have two `ExcelApp.Quit`: one before the `CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR:` and one after. Given that, I suppose it's ok to have `Exit Sub` right before `CLOSE_FILE_ON_ERROR:`?

Comment: @Ans:  You are correct.  @ Peh: Sorry... I didn't mean to step on toes.  Your answer is completely the correct way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the below code where I kill the application like Excel, Chrome and Internet Explorer. You can use the below code with the `On Error Goto` error handler.

```
Public Function fnkilltask()
    Dim objWMIService
    Dim colProcessList
    Dim objProcess
    Dim strComputer

    strComputer = "." 
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")  ' Task mgr
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name in ('EXCEL.EXE','Chrome.exe','iexplore.exe') ") 

    For Each objProcess in colProcessList 
        objProcess.Terminate() 
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I think using a correct error handling would be the better idea.

Comment: @Peh : I have edited the my comment and it can be merged with the error handler as your answer suggested.

Comment: @Vityata : No, This code does not belongs to me :P, i got part of it from Stackoverflow. This code is very strong as it actually kills all the application mentioned in the code. This is just a vba version Task Manager Kill

Comment: @nishitdey - well, I saw the part with `EXCEL.EXE','Chrome.exe','iexplore.exe` and actually thought that this looks like an overkill.

Comment: I still think that `ExcelApp.Quit` is a way better to end an Excel instance regularly than killing a process the hard way.

Comment: @Vityata : I am too lazy to shutdown the application

Comment: I'll try it out, but why do you kill Chrome.exe as well? I need the internet, after all. And the problem is, wouldn't you method kill the visible excel applications as well? I currently do the same manually - open the task manager and kill EXCEL.EXE, but to do so I need to get rid of visible needed application, which upsets me.

Comment: @ans Have a look at my answer then to specifically close the invisible Excel application only and to leave all other Excel applications open.